# Phantom row when dropping file into DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I want do drag'n'drop files (file names) into a DataGridView.
I have a Form with the following code.
When I click Button1 both counts return Zero.
When I drag a file over the DataGridView `dt.Rows.Count` returns Zero while `dt.DefaultView.Count`returns One. Why is that?
I'm under the impression that when I first click the button an drag a file afterwards both counts then return zero. Do I have to Initialize the DataGridView or the datatable in special manner when Dragging is to occur?

```vb
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents bs As New BindingSource
Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable

Public Sub New()
    ' Dieser Aufruf ist für den Designer erforderlich.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Fügen Sie Initialisierungen nach dem InitializeComponent()-Aufruf hinzu.
    Dim col As DataColumn = New DataColumn("col1", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add(col)
    dt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt.Columns(0)}
    bs.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.DataPropertyName = "col1", .Name = "col1", .HeaderText = "col1", .ReadOnly = True})
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Debug.Print(dt.Rows.Count)
    Debug.Print(dt.DefaultView.Count)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragEnter
    Debug.Print(dt.Rows.Count)
    Debug.Print(dt.DefaultView.Count)
End Sub
End Class
```

Addition:
As a commentor suggests: I don't want to know how Drop works and that I need to set `effect` and that I need Drop-Code.
I stumbled upon this when I called `DataGridView.Datasource.DefaultView.ToTable()`.
I just posted this minimal sample that shows there's a difference whether I count at a random point in time (Button click) or whether I count during a Drag'n'Drop operation.
Why?

I delved further into this. In the DragEnter handler `dt.DefaultView.addNewRow` is set to an object. I call `dt.AcceptChanges()` and the phantom row vanishes. Why/by whom/when is it created in the first place?

`dt.DefaultView.Item(0).Row` exists in the dragEnter handler and contains one column with a DBNULL.value

Comment: 1 could be the column header or new row? not sure exactly. you need .DragEnter and .DragDrop events, and set DragDropEffects.All, as well as pull the file from the e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)().ToString() array.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `dt.Rows.Count` or `dt.DefaultView.Count` at all?  one counts rows, one counts views

Comment: how would we know since you didn't post your full code? also, dragging a file probably refreshes the view, and rowfilter is applied. that's why... but what is this row? don't know...

Comment: btw, have you even tried to inspect it? `dt.DefaultView.Item(0).Row`